# How to create multiple containers with dependencies using Google Cloud Builder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I am looking for help creating a `cloudbuild.yaml` file for my application. My application has a base image derived from `phython:2-onbuild` and then two additional images that derive from that base image. I have three separate `Dockerfile`s in my project for each. Is there an example of doing this that someone could point me towards?

For example, my base image `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM python:2-onbuild
# This will execute pip install requirements.txt and get all required python packages installed
# It will also ensure the current directly, minus anything in .dockerignore is copied over to the image
# The web server image and the worker image can then simply inherit from this.
```

Then subsequently, I create a web server image and a worker image. The worker is intended to be run as a `CronJob`.

My web server `Dockerfile` is like so:

```
FROM myapp-base

RUN chmod +x ./main_runner.sh
RUN chmod +w static/login.html
RUN chmod +w static/index.html
CMD ./main_runner.sh
```

and my worker `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM myapp-base

RUN chmod +x worker_runner.sh
CMD python ./run_worker.py
```

Currently, my local `docker-compose.yaml` ties it all together by creating the `myapp-base` image and making it available by that name so the other images can derive from it. What is the equivalent in cloud build?

Answer (score 4):

[This example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/docker/cloudbuild.yaml), from our open-sourced "docker" build-step, creates 3 different images from 3 different Dockerfiles. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks David! I am checking it out. Looks really promising.

Comment: So, David, I am looking to create a base image, then create two other types of containers that derive from it. The structure of cloud build seems to dictate running several steps, then finally pushing images. I would like to push an image as part of step 1 and then create the next few images by pulling the recently pushed image. Not sure if this is covered ...

Comment: @Raj That's not currently very easy in a single build. You could use the docker builder to run "docker push" in your build steps, but you don't need to push the base image before building images based on it. Simply building later images with the first image as its FROM will use that image you just built. Then you can push all three images at the end of your build.

Comment: Thanks @JasonHall. That helps. I don't need to push my base image before building the rest as long as cloud build can get to them. I would like to use the same `Dockerfile` for my local builds as well as cloud builds. How do I tag and reference my base image in that case? I am assuming I'll have to tag it as `gcr.io/xxx` something. Will that work for both local as well as cloud?

Comment: Yes, that will work -- just reference the local image in the FROM directive of your `Dockerfile` the same way you would reference it by name in a subsequent build step.